# How do I append XML to another XML document OUTSIDE all the nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Very Simple. I have 2 documents

Doc1

```
<Person>
 <Name>Bob</Name>
</Person>
```

Doc2

```
<Animal>
 <Name>Zippy</Name>
</Animal>
```

And I want to create

Doc3

```
<Person>
 <Name>Bob</Name>
</Person>
<Animal>
 <Name>Zippy</Name>
</Animal>
```

The code I have below is close but insert the XML INSIDE the other one and I don't want that

```
string xmlUserData = GetUserData(fileId);
        string xmlPurchaseDate  = GetPurchaseData();

        XDocument xdocUserData = XDocument.Parse(xmlUserData);
        XDocument xdocPurchaseDate = XDocument.Parse(xmlPurchaseDate);


        XElement xe1 = xdocUserData.Descendants("USERDATA").FirstOrDefault();
        XElement xe2 = xdocPurchaseDate.Descendants("PurchaseAdvice").FirstOrDefault();
        xe1.Add(xe2.Nodes());
```

Comment: Your final "document" isn't an XML document - an XML document can only have one root element.

Comment: Jon is right, what you are trying to produce is an xml fragment.

Comment: hacky way of doing it is generate 2 xml documents as files then append the two files together. However, as the others pointed out, this is not an xml document

Comment: the better question I think is why do you want to do this

Comment: Is there a way to wrap a it in a <root></root> to make it valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can wrap elements in a root:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
XElement rootElement = new XElement("Root");
rootElement.Add(new XElement("person"));
rootElement.Add(new XElement("animal"));
doc.Add(rootElement);
```

gives:

```
<Root>
  <person />
  <animal />
</Root>
```

Comment: Yes! I swapped out the new XElement with the ones I have.

Comment: Yes, I thought I would leave you a little work to do :)